# Applying a simple noise model to the ghz state

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, noise

I want to calculate the effect of a specific noise model on the GHZ state but fail to do so. I think I am missing some basic rules established for working with operations on density matrices. More on the core of my problem below.

**Noise model:**

I am considering a dephasing noise, that changes the state of a single qubit in the following way: $$\rho\mapsto\mathcal{E}(\rho)=(1-p)\rho+p\cdot \sigma_z\rho\sigma_z.$$ Furthermore, I am considering a finite number of qubits, which let's me work with matrices when considering operations or measurements on qubits.

Given a system that consists of multiple qubits, I want the noise acting on that system to be regarded as the above described dephasing noise acting on every single qubit independently (as if each qubit "lives" in its own universe). If you consider two qubits with states $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$, you'd have to compute $$\left[(1-p)\rho_{1}+p\cdot \sigma_z\rho_{1}\sigma_z\right]\otimes\left[(1-p)\rho_{2}+p\cdot \sigma_z\rho_{2}\sigma_z\right].$$
This calculation is based on rules for composite systems that are in mixed states, often regarded as postulates of quantum mechanics (Nielsen and Chuang call it the fourth postulate in their famous book). That postulate tells you that the state one system, where the states of each subsystem is known, can be written with the tensor product.

**Question/Problem:**

Let me try to express the problem I am facing: I want to compute the effect of the above defined noise on the GHZ-state and I cannot figure out how. The core of the problem I have shows when trying to calculate the following:

What is the action of said noise model on two qubits that are in the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|00>+|11>$?

**My thoughts:**

**- part 1: some fundamental mathematical aspects**

1. Operations on qubits in pure states:

When working with operations on qubits in pure states, operations are formally described by matrices and are linear. By definition the effect of two operations (described by two unitary matrices $A$ and $B$) acting independently on a two state system is calculated along $$(A\otimes B)\left(\sum_i a_i|v_i\rangle\otimes|w_i\rangle\right),$$ where one uses basic linear algebra (e.g. also the tensor product as in linear algebra). Using linear algebra this is found to be the same as $$\sum_i a_i A|v_i\rangle\otimes B|w_i\rangle.$$

2. Tensor product and mixed states

Given two systems in two mixed states $\rho$ and $\sigma$, the state of the composite system is formally described by $\rho\otimes \sigma$. This can be derived from the definition of separable (pure) states and the definition of mixed states.

3. Operations on qubits that are in mixed states

Those operations are also described by unitary matrices $U$. One has to calculate $$U\rho U^{\dagger}.$$ One can derive this from the definition of operators acting on qubits in pure states and the definition of mixed states. Using 2. one can derivate analogously that for two qubits in mixed states $\rho$ and $\sigma$ the effect of operations $A$ and $B$ (that act independently on the two qubits) is caculated along $$A\rho A^{\dagger}\otimes B\sigma B^{\dagger}.\tag{1}$$

**- part 2: trying to calculate the effect of said noise model on the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|00>+|11>$ by using the fundamental mathematical aspects**

Following 1. one can readily calculate e.g. $$U\otimes V \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|00>+|11>\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[U|0>\otimes V|0>+U|1>\otimes V|1>\right].$$ Also in case the state under the noise model is of the form $\rho\otimes\sigma$, one can work with equation (1). Because the density matrix of the 2-qubit ghz state is of the form $\rho\otimes\sigma+\rho_2\otimes\sigma_2+...$ none of the above mathematical aspects can be applied. Linearity of the dephasing noise map wouldn't solve this either. The problem seems to be that for mixed states, operations cannot be described by matrices. Therefore the second problem seems to be the given operation (the dephasing noise and its mathematical representation).

Comment: Can you make this more concise? E.g. a simpler problem where the difficulty is already there? Is the problem that the state is not a density matrix (then write it as one!), or that your noise acts on more than one qubit? If both are a problem, ask them separately!